# How to use Spock in Java Project

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, spock

I have a question about [Spock FrameWork.](http://spockframework.org/) It's a test framework for my opinion it's greater then JUnit. Spoke requires Groovy lang. 
I'm using Gradle build tool.

I used it in Groovy project and now **I want to use Spock in Java Project**!
Do you have any ideas how to do it?

*UPDATED*
changed typo.

Comment: I think you mean "Spock" not "Spoke". Use the question's head line with correct spelling for a Google search and you're done.

Comment: You should add the relevant dependencies of Spock based on your Building tool Maven/Gradle. After building your application you can use it easily using your IDE create new test should expose you the option to create new Spock test. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rotem Suggested, you just need to add the dependencies to your build.gradle file. Here is a basic example:

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

// Spock works with Java 1.6 and above
sourceCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
  // Spock releases are available from Maven Central
  mavenCentral()
  // Spock snapshots are available from the Sonatype OSS snapshot repository
  maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
  // mandatory dependencies for using Spock
  compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.10"
  testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4"
}
```